# Sending a Protonmail / PGP email in PHP

Tags: php, pgp

I'm trying to write a simple script to send emails from Protonmail's API which expects the emails to be PGP encoded. Here's what I have so far, it successfully creates a draft but fails at the last step sending the draft, with the message "invalid message body key". Where is the error?

```
<?php
function send_email($to, $subject, $message, $pmconfig = 'json encoded protonmail keys', $from){
//load config
        $pmconfig = json_decode($pmconfig, true);
        if(!$pmconfig) return -6;
        if(isset($pmconfig['expires']) && $pmconfig['expires'] <= time()) return -7; //expired pm config
        if(!isset($pmconfig['senders'][$from[1]])) return -8; //invalid sender

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: application/vnd.protonmail.v1+json', 'x-pm-appversion: Web_3.16.20', 'x-pm-apiversion: 3', 'Content-Type: application/json', 'x-pm-uid: '.$pmconfig['uid'], 'Authorization: Bearer '.$pmconfig['auth']]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $tor_host );
        $baseurl = 'https://protonirockerxow.onion';
//look up recipient on Proton keyserver
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseurl.'/api/keys?Email='.urlencode($to));
        $recipient = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        if($recipient['Code'] != 1000)
            return array_merge(['stage' => 'recipient'], $recipient);
//session key
        $messagekey = random_bytes(32);

        $senderkey = ''; //todo: parse sender key from the given public key
        $senderkeyid = '';
        if(isset($recipient['Keys'][0]['PublicKey'])){
            $recipient['Keys'][0]['PublicKey'];
            $recipientkeyid = ''; //todo: parse key from the given public key
            $recipientkeyn = '';
//session key for recipient
            $recipientkey = hex2bin(gz_key($messagekey, $recipientkeyn, $recipientkeyid));
        }
//encrypt session key using my own pgp key
        $key = hex2bin(gz_key($messagekey, $senderkey, $senderkeyid));
        $body = hex2bin(gz_enc(hex2bin(gz_sign(gz_data($message), $senderkeyid)), $messagekey)); 
//create message as draft
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseurl.'/api/messages');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(['Message' => ['ToList' => [['label' => $to, 'Name' => $to, 'Address' => $to, "encrypt" => false, "invalid" => false, "isContactGroup" => false, "isEO" => false, "isPgp" => false, "isPgpMime" => false, "loadCryptInfo" => false, "sign" => false, "warnings" => []]], 'CCList' => [], 'BCCList' => [], 'Subject' => $subject, 'Unread' => 0, 'MIMEType' => 'text/html', 'Flags' => 0, 'Sender' => ['Name' => $from[0], 'Address' => $from[1]], 'AddressID' => $pmconfig['senders'][$from[1]]['id'], 'Body' => armor($key.$body)], 'id' => '', 'AttachmentKeyPackets' => []]));
        $draft = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        //echo json_encode(['Message' => ['ToList' => [['label' => $to, 'Name' => $to, 'Address' => $to, "encrypt" => false, "invalid" => false, "isContactGroup" => false, "isEO" => false, "isPgp" => false, "isPgpMime" => false, "loadCryptInfo" => false, "sign" => false, "warnings" => []]], 'CCList' => [], 'BCCList' => [], 'Subject' => $subject, 'Unread' => 0, 'MIMEType' => 'text/html', 'Flags' => 0, 'Sender' => ['Name' => $from[0], 'Address' => $from[1]], 'AddressID' => $pmconfig['senders'][$from[1]]['id'], 'Body' => armor($key.$body)], 'id' => '', 'AttachmentKeyPackets' => []]);
        if($draft['Code'] != 1000)
            return array_merge(['stage' => 'draft'], $draft);


//send the message ****THIS IS THE PART THAT DOESN'T WORK****


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseurl.'/api/messages/'.urlencode($draft['Message']['ID']));

        if(isset($recipientkey) && !empty($recipientkey)) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(['id' => $draft['Message']['ID'], 'Packages' => [['Flags' => 1, 'Addresses' => [$to => ['Type' => 1, 'Signature' => 0, 'AttachmentKeyPackets' => [], 'BodyKeyPacket' => base64_encode($recipientkey)]], 'MIMEType' => 'text/html', 'Body' => base64_encode($body), 'Type' => 1]]])); 
        else curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(['id' => $draft['Message']['ID'], 'Packages' => [['Flags' => 13, 'Addresses' => [$to => ['Type' => 4, 'Signature' => 0]], 'MIMEType' => 'text/html', 'Body' => base64_encode($body), 'Type' => 4, 'AttachmentKeys' => [], 'BodyKey' => ['Algorithm' => 'aes256', 'Key' => base64_encode($messagekey)]]]]));
        $sent = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        //echo json_encode(['id' => $draft['Message']['ID'], 'Packages' => [['Flags' => 1, 'Addresses' => [$to => ['Type' => 1, 'Signature' => 0, 'AttachmentKeyPackets' => [], 'BodyKeyPacket' => base64_encode($recipientkey)]], 'MIMEType' => 'text/html', 'Body' => base64_encode($body), 'Type' => 1]]]);
        //echo json_encode(['id' => $draft['Message']['ID'], 'Packages' => [['Flags' => 1, 'Addresses' => [$to => ['Type' => 4, 'Signature' => 0]], 'MIMEType' => 'text/html', 'Body' => base64_encode($body), 'Type' => 4, 'AttachmentKeys' => [], 'BodyKey' => ['Key' => base64_encode($messagekey), 'Algorithm' => 'aes256']]]]);
        //echo base64_encode($body); die();
        curl_close($ch);
        if($sent['Code'] != 1000)
            return array_merge(['stage' => 'sending'], $sent);
        else 
            return true;
    }
//crc for armor
function crc24($data) {
    $crc = 0x00b704ce;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); $i++) {
        $crc ^= (ord($data[$i]) & 255) << 16;
        for ($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++) {
            $crc <<= 1;
            if ($crc & 0x01000000) $crc ^= 0x01864cfb;
        }
    }
    return $crc & 0x00ffffff;   
}
function armor($data, $headers = ['Version: OpenPGP.js v4.7.2']){
    return "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----\r\n".implode("\r\n", $headers)."\r\n\r\n".trim(chunk_split(base64_encode($data), 60))."\r\n=".base64_encode(substr(pack('N', crc24($data)), 1))."\r\n-----END PGP MESSAGE-----\r\n";
}
function bitlength($data) {
    return str_pad(dechex((strlen($data) - 1) * 8 + (int)floor(log(ord($data[0]), 2)) + 1), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).bin2hex($data);
}
//builds each of the data packets in a pgp message
function gen_data($type, $version, $data){
    $type = bin2hex(chr($type));
    if(!is_null($version)) $data = bin2hex(chr($version)).$data;
    $count = strlen($data)/2;
    if($count < 192) $header = [$type, str_pad(dechex($count), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)];
    else if($count <= 8383){
        $sec = ($count-192) & 0xff;
        $header = [$type,str_pad(dechex((($count - $sec - 192) >> 8)+192), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT), str_pad(dechex($sec), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)];
    }else $header = [$type, 'ff'.str_pad(dechex($count), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)];   
    //var_dump($header); var_dump($data);
    return implode($header).$data;
}
//encrypt message w/ session key
function gz_enc($data, $messagekey, $random_octet = null){
    if(is_null($random_octet)) $random_octet = random_bytes(16);
    $encoded = $random_octet.substr($random_octet, -2).gen_data(200, 2, bin2hex(gzcompress($data)).'d314');
    return gen_data(210, 1, bin2hex(openssl_encrypt($encoded.sha1($encoded, true), 'AES-256-CFB', $messagekey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, '0000000000000000')));
}
//encrypt session key w/ pgp key
function gz_key($messagekey, $n, $keyid, $e = '010001'){
    $M = '09'.bin2hex($messagekey).str_pad(dechex(array_sum(unpack('C*', $messagekey)) % 65536), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $in = gmp_powm(gmp_init('0002'.bin2hex(random_bytes(256-(strlen($M)/2)-3)).'00'.$M, 16), gmp_init($e, 16), gmp_init($n, 16));
    $encrypted = str_pad(gmp_export($in), 256, chr(0), STR_PAD_LEFT);  
    return gen_data(193, 3, $keyid.'01'.bitlength($encrypted));
}
function gz_data($message, $filename = 'msg.txt', $time = null, $format = null){
    if(is_null($time)) $time = time();
    if(is_null($format)) $format = (mb_detect_encoding($message, 'UTF-8', true) == 'UTF-8') ? 'u' : ctype_print($message) ? 't' : 'b';
    if($format != 'b') $message = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", str_replace("\r", "\n", str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $message)));
    return gen_data(203, null, bin2hex($format).bin2hex(strlen($filename)).bin2hex($filename).bin2hex(pack('N', $time)).bin2hex($message));
}
function gz_sign($data, $keyid, $type = 1, $alg = 1, $time = null){
    return $data;
    if(is_null($time)) $time = time();
    $prefix = hex2bin('ca23');
    $sign = hex2bin(''); //todo: generate signature

    $hash = 8; //sha256
    $nested = 1;
    $hashed = chr(2).pack('N', $time);
    $hashed = chr(strlen($hashed)).$hashed;
    $hashed = chr(strlen($hashed)).$hashed;
    $unhashed = chr(10).hex2bin($keyid);
    $unhashed = chr(strlen($unhashed)).$unhashed;
    $unhashed = chr(strlen($unhashed)).$unhashed;

    return gen_data(196, 3, bin2hex(chr($type).chr($hash).chr($alg))).$keyid.bin2hex(chr($nested)).$data.gen_data(194, 4, bin2hex(chr($type).chr($alg).chr($hash).$hashed.$unhashed.$prefix.bitlength($sign))); //chr($type).chr($alg).chr($hash).$hashed.$unhashed.hex2bin($prefix).hex2bin(bitlength($sign)));
}
```

for what it's worth, I tried using a library at the start, and ran into even more issues, so I ended up just taking snippets from it to end up with this. I'm pretty sure I'm close, since the draft my script creates does show up and is fully legible.

Comment: There's a lot of code here and it's very hard to follow. I suggest you strip out the bits that you know work, and allow people to focus on the bits that don't.

Comment: I marked the part that doesn't work, but I figured without the rest of it for context that bit by itself isn't very meaningful. I'm guessing my `body` parameter is wrong, but not sure what it should be.

Comment: Did you ever get this working/is there a github for this? I'd love to help you get it fixed and use it myself. Are you aware of the old api html document that is archived on peer to peer services? I think it has the solution to your issue.

Comment: @yes I just settled for using this: https://github.com/emersion/hydroxide and PHPMailer for SMTP interface with Hydroxide, which of course is not quite as neat or as stable as this script would have been, but it did what I needed. The code I posted actually has all of the API bits done, it was just the PGP encryption bit we were having trouble with. Let me know if you figre it out though, would be nice to know what the problem was.